# mongodb: Specify the Threshold for Slow Operations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I always have a problem with add a config in mongod.cfg.

Now I want to enable operationProfiling according [this suggestion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/):
for Specify the Threshold for Slow Operations

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: C:\Mongo\log\mongod.log
    logAppend: true
storage:
    journal:
        enabled: true
    dbPath: C:\Mongo\db
operationProfiling:
    mode: 2
    slowOpThresholdMs: 500
    slowOpSampleRate: 1.0
```

but when i want to start mongodb from service I got error:

```
Error1053:The service did not response to the start or control request in a timely fashion
```

where the cfg file is wrong?actually without

```
operationProfiling:
    mode: 2
    slowOpThresholdMs: 500
    slowOpSampleRate: 1.0
```

service is started but, when I added this config I got error.

****** Edit ******

I am using mongodb 3.6

Comment: There should be more information on the error in your MongoDB log file, but the likely problem is that you have specified an invalid [`operationProfiling.mode`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#operation-profiling-configuration-options). This should be a string value of "all" if you are after the equivalent of `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`. If changing your `mode` to a string value doesn't work, please  confirm the specific version of MongoDB server that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Mode is a string value, default is off, so in your case you need on, as following:
mode: on

Answer (score 0):

I hope it should work, please try as below:

```
operationProfiling:
    mode: slowOp (Different modes: off, slowOp, all)
    slowOpThresholdMs: 500
    slowOpSampleRate: 1.0
```

[operationProfiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b58DU.png)

Please go through below the URL for more information on this ([MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/configuration-options/#operationprofiling-options))

Answer (score 0):

Well, operationProfiling.mode support string value only. By default mode is off. The other two options are slowOp and all. In my case, I use the 'all'.
In your case, it should be like

```
operationProfiling:
 mode: "all"
 slowOpThresholdMs: 500
 slowOpSampleRate: 1.0
```

For further info please follow the link
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#operationProfiling.mode